# Same Inheritance code working differently on java and c++

Tags: java, c++, oop, inheritance, binding

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    class shape
    {
        public: void draw();
    };
    void shape::draw()
    {
        cout<<"drawing shape\n";
    }
     class circle:public shape
    {
        public: void draw();
    };
    void circle::draw()
    {
        cout<<"drawing circle\n";
    }
    int main()
    {
        shape* sptr;
        circle* cptr;
        sptr=new shape();
        cptr=new circle();
        sptr->draw();
        cptr->draw();
        cout<<"****************************\n";
        sptr=cptr;
        sptr->draw();
    }



*********************************JAVA CODE*****************************
public class Circle extends Shape{


    public void draw() {
        System.out.println("Drawing Circle");
    }

}
public class Shape {
    public void draw()
    {
        System.out.println("Drawing the shape");
    }
}
public class SimulateShape {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Shape shape=new Shape();
        Circle circle=new Circle();
        shape.draw();
        circle.draw();
        System.out.println("************************");
        shape=circle;

        shape.draw();

    }
}
```

Even though both the code looks the same the output produced by both the code is very different. In java the base class reference is able to call the derived class draw but in c++ the case is opposite the base class pointer is calling its own draw method. Don't know the reason behind this problem.

The output of C++ is

```
drawing shape
drawing circle
************************
drawing shape
```

The output of the java is

```
Drawing the shape
Drawing Circle
************************
Drawing Circle
```

Comment: It's been a long time since I've done any C++ but I think you need to declare `shape::draw()` as `virtual` to allow overriding.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no PROGRAMMING issue whatsoever.

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert: You had better read the examples more carefully - the C++ code has the 'Shape' class first, while the Java code has the 'Circle' class first.

Comment: @JulianF.Weinert: It's certainly a programming language issue! Java methods are implicitly virtual, while C++ requires the keyword.

Comment: Sorry, @DaveDoknjas! I reread your question. It's still not clear from the question _itself_, only from your comment. Please edit your question and make that clear. I take it back, but it's still not a good question – sorry.

Comment: The quetion title implies that the intention is to compare between C++ and Java for a specifie behaviour, rather than finding error in the question itself ! I find it very misleading ...

Comment: @HAG: There is no error in the question - the Java code and the C++ code simply have the classes in a different order, but that shouldn't cause too much confusion!

Comment: To everyone who is hastily downvoting the question or rushing to comment: the question posed is perfectly valid and often asked and is simply related to Java methods being implicitly virtual and C++ requiring the 'virtual' keyword.  If anything, it could be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas there is ! He misses 'virtual' in his C++ code ( as per your own answer ) ... while the desired behaviour is not clear at all, to the point you have to cover two different behaviours in your answer .. so, why he compare between java and C++ codes ? What did he try to achieve exactly ?

Comment: @HAG: He is asking why the difference in behavior - and the difference is due to the C++ code not using the 'virtual' keyword.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas right ! May be I would find it less confusing if he just had his desired output and only C++ code, which I think it will be enough in this case to have a specific/clear question.. thanks for your comments.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas thanks man

Answer (score 1):

Java methods are implicitly virtual, so you would want your C++ code to use the 'virtual' keyword in order to reproduce the same behavior as your Java example:

```
class Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw();
};
class Circle : public Shape
{
public:
    virtual void draw() override; //C++11 'override'
};
```

Alternatively, if you want the Java code to have the same behavior as your C++ example, you would need to declare the Java methods as 'final':

```
public class Shape
{
    public final void draw()
    {
        ...
    }
}
public class Circle extends Shape
{
    public final void draw()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```